# Unable to connect MongoDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating an application with nodejs and electron. I want to use mongodb to store data and stuff but i am having a bit of a difficulty while trying to connect mongodb. I am using robomongo and i can connect to database with it but when i try to connect in my js file i get an error. error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: mongo.open is not a function
```

here's my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var mongo = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
mongo.open((err, mongo) => {
  var db = mongo.db('aab');
  console.log('Connected!');
  if(err) throw err;
  mongo.close();
});
```

thanks for helping :)

Comment: `MongoClient` doesn't have an `open()` method. Did you mean [`connect()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#.connect)?

Comment: well actually no, i was digging some documentation and in official guides they’ve used .open function? ref: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

Comment: I bet when you do `npm ls`, your `mongodb` version is not going to be `@1.4.9`... that's pretty old.

Comment: are you using the correct npm package for the mongodb module?

Comment: idk if im biased, but i personally prefer the `mongoose` package to handle mongodb things

Comment: well i see mongoose is a better option comparing to that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no open. Here is an example:

```
let mongoUri;
let dbName;
const collectionName = 'collection';
let mongo = {};

const setEnv = (req) => {
  mongoUri = req.env.mongoUri;
  dbName = req.env.dbName;
  if (dbName === '' || mongoUri === '') {
    console.warn('no request.env');
  }
};

const mongoDbConnection = async (req) => {
  setEnv(req);
  try {
    if ( !mongo.client || mongo.uri !== mongoUri || !mongo.client.isConnected() || !mongo.db ) {
      mongo.uri = mongoUri;
      let options = { useNewUrlParser: true };
      const c = await MongoClient.connect(mongo.uri, options);
      mongo.client = c ;
      mongo.db = await mongo.client.db(dbName);
    }
    return mongo.db;
  } catch (e) {
    throw `Mongo connection failed \n ${e}`;
  }
};

const getCollection = async (req) => {
  try {
    const db = await mongoDbConnection(req);
    console.log('collection connected');
    return await db.collection(collectionName);
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```